# Creating an Object with a dynamic Array

Tags: javascript, sapui5

As for my table binding I need to convert this JSON Object :

```
{"id":"txn_18Ptu52eZvKYlo2C9c8ejhap","amount":999,"availableOn":1467331200,"created":1466773164,"currency":"usd"}
```

into something like that:

```
{"data":[{"id":"txn_18Ptu52eZvKYlo2C9c8ejhap","amount":999,"availableOn":1467331200,"created":1466773164,"currency":"usd"}]}
```

I tried this one:

```
success : function(data1, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var resp = [data1];
                    var response = {data: resp};
                    var oJSonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(response);
                    this.getView().setModel(oJSonModel);
```

data1 is the object we get above, then I stored it into an array which is named resp, and then I tried to store that into a new object, but it went wrong I guess, because it seems that I stored only the second entry of that array because my debugger showed me this:

```
response = Object {data: Array[1]}
```

and then of course my binding didn't work.....

Edit here my full code:

```
sap.ui.define([
    'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
    'sap/m/MessageToast',
    'somepath/balance/model/formatter'
], function(Controller, MessageToast, formatter) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("somepath.balance.controller.Balance", {

        formatter: formatter,

        onInit: function() {
            this.getView().setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel());
        },

        onTransactionList: function() {
            this.getView().getModel().loadData("/balance/retrieveTransacationList?limit=" + this.getView().byId("quantity").getValue());
        },

        onTransactionByTransactionId: function() {
            var that = this;

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "/balance/retrieveTransaction?transactionId=" + that.getView().byId("searchById").getValue(),
                processData: true,
                dataType: "text",
                async: false,

                success: function(data1, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var resp = [];
                    resp.push(data1);
                    var response = {
                        data: resp[0]
                    };
                    var oJSonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(response);
                    that.getView.setModel(oJSonModel);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    var sErrorText = "" + jqXHR.status + " - " + errorThrown + " - " + jqXHR.responseText;
                    MessageToast.show(sErrorText);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

my table in my view:

```
    <t:Table id="transactionUiTable" 
                columnHeaderVisible="true" 
                selectionMode="Single" 
                selectionBehavior="RowSelector" 
                enableColumnReordering="false" 
                enableGrouping="false" 
                showColumnVisibilityMenu="false" 
                enableSelectAll="false" 
                enableCustomFilter="false"
                enableBusyIndicator="false"
                rows="{path: '/data'}" 
                rowSelectionChange="onTableSelectionChange">
                    <t:toolbar>
                        <Toolbar id="toolbar">
                                <Input width="15%" id="searchById" value=""/> 
                                <Button text="{i18n>searchTransaction}" type="Emphasized" icon="sap-icon://search" press="onTransactionByTransactionId"/> 
                                <Button text="{i18n>customerTransactionlist}" type="Emphasized" icon="sap-icon://search" press="onCustomerTransactionList"/>
                                <ToolbarSpacer/>
                                <Input width="5%" id="quantity" value=""/>
                                <Button text="{i18n>transactionList}" type="Unstyled" press="onTransactionList"/>
                                <Button icon="sap-icon://action-settings" type="Default"/>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </t:toolbar>
                 <t:columns>
                        <t:Column id="Id" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label id="labelId" text="{i18n>transactionId}"/>
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{id}"/>
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column id="columnDatetime" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label id="labelDatetime" text="{i18n>datetime}"/>
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{parts: [                
                                {path: 'created'}               
                                ],               
                                formatter : '.formatter.date'}"/>
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column id="columnAmount" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label id="labelAmount" text="{i18n>amount}"/>
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{
                                             parts: [
                                             {path: 'amount'}, 
                                             {path: 'currency'}
                                            ],
                                            type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency',
                                            formatOptions: {
                                             showMeasure: false}}"/>
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column id="columnCurrency" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label id="labelCurrency" text="{i18n>currency}"/>
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{currency}"/>
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column id="columnFee" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label id="labelFee" text="{i18n>fee}"/>
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{
                                             parts: [
                                             {path: 'fee'}, 
                                             {path: 'currency'}
                                            ],
                                            type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency',
                                            formatOptions: {
                                             showMeasure: false}}"/>
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column id="columnNet" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label id="labelNet" text="{i18n>net}"/>
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{
                                             parts: [
                                             {path: 'net'}, 
                                             {path: 'currency'}
                                            ],
                                            type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency',
                                            formatOptions: {
                                             showMeasure: false}}"/>
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column id="columnType" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label id="labelType" text="{i18n>type}"/>
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{type}"/>
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>
                            <t:Column id="columnStatus" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label id="labelStatus" text="{i18n>status}"/>
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{status}"/>
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>
                    </t:columns>
                </t:Table>
```

Comment: `obj.data[0]` should work.

Comment: 1 in `Array[1]` is the length. not the index.

Comment: thanks that worked but I got now problems with my JsonModel because I get this Error: sap-ui-core.js:71 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setModel' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it this way:

```
var resp = [];
resp.push(data1);
```

to make it a proper array

Comment: yeah that worked so far, but I got still the Error with my setModel :    sap-ui-core.js:71 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setModel' of undefined

Comment: Make sure you get a correct reference to your view; right now it most likely resolves to `undefined`, resulting in the error you're getting

Comment: well I think I did the right reference, but it's still not working is there a way I could send you my code in private because if I write it in a comment it's unreadable....

Comment: No, it's better to edit/update your question with the additional code. Where do you set `this.oView`, and is it defined in the same class as your `success` event handler?

Comment: I updated my question with full code of my controller, I guess you don't need my xml view page

Comment: Like I said before, `this.oView` is never defined. Either assign it, or simply use `this.getView()` instead

Comment: that was right but I still have this Error now: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setModel' of undefined but I looked up the response of the network and that should normally work

Comment: Again, have you assigned your view to `this.oView`??

Comment: I used what u said simply just `this.getView.setModel(oJSonModel);` wasn't that what you advised me?

Comment: I now see you have used it in an inner function; in that case, assign `this` to another variable `self` outside the inner function and use `self.getView().setModel(oJSonModel)` instead

Comment: I already did that with var that = this; I updated my question now you see the current state of my code I got this Error now after changing from oView to getView: **Uncaught TypeError: that.getView.byId is not a function**

Comment: You made a typo: it should be `getView()`, not `getView` (it's a function, not a variable)

Comment: the misery with Errors keeps on going now the Error changed to: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

Comment: for which request?

Comment: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: There should be more errors surrounding it, either in the console or in your controller / view

Comment: Yes I got these Errors, because I dont have created those files yet, but why didn't I get them earlier ? I don't think its really the "true" problem, but you seem to have far more experience then me so I will listen to you Sir! **sap-ui-core.js:71 GET https://webidetesting12532-.........neo.ondemand.com/webapp/i18n/i18n_en_US.properties 404 (Not Found)** I got this Error 4 times (btw I changed the url to hide it)

Comment: Those i18n files are save to ignore; but `sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js Failed to load resource` message is strange. Are there no other error messages? Is your XMLView and controller class well-formed?

Comment: BTW, there's still a reference to `this.oView` in your `onTransactionList` method

Comment: nope but I guess those Error is relative to those i18n files, because the rest of my controller function works pretty well and all the pages get loaded so theres nothing wrong with my view neither....

Comment: updated everything still not working I see in my F12 under "Network" that he goes on that page and loads that JSON Data so its some kind of my binding problem it doesnt work to wrap that into an array.....

Comment: One other thing: you are calling your service with datatype `text`; are you sure this is correct? I would suspect it must be `json` since that's what you're adding to your array, not a string

Comment: thats true, I corrected that too but its still the same Error

Comment: I upated my question and implemented my table from my view but there should be everything okay

Comment: Can you debug and see whether you see a response from your ajax call? Is data being returned? And what does the model structure look like after it's been set? Does it match the binding of your table?

Comment: yes I get the right response back its the response you see in my question `{"id":"txn_18Ptu52eZvKY....` well that thing with the binding is I guess the problem, I'm not sure whether my wrapping worked right now I would assume it went wrong....

Comment: Check wit the SAPUI5 disgnostics tool (Cmd Alt Shift S) whether your bindings are correct; your code looks a bit weird with all the re-initializations of a model as well as not using async (better use setProperty of your model rather than setting a new model every time) Sorry I can't help you further

Comment: I cant use this of your solutions for this case too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053191/changing-the-bindings-of-a-table-by-clicking-on-a-button/38053602#38053602 kinda implementing this in my `rows="{path: '/data'}" ` kinda saying if theres no /data path then just take this path '/' ?